# Vba code to open hyperlink from a particular range of a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

```
Sheets("A").Select
LastRowA = Sheets("A").Cells(Rows.Count, 
"B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2:B" & LastRowA).Select
Sheets("A").Range("B2:B" & LastRowA).Follow Hyperlink
```

I am having a worksheet in which in a B column, there are hyperlinks(path of excel files), I want to browse that column and open the files from that hyperlink. My above code is giving "Object Property 438 not support error".Kindly help me with the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```
Sub FollowHyperlink()
Dim rng As Range
For each rng in Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Edited Code based on discussion:

```
Sub FollowHyperlink()
Dim rng As Range
Dim strAddress As String
For Each rng In Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    ElseIf rng.HasFormula And InStr(rng.Formula, "=HYPERLINK(") > 0 Then
        strAddress = Split(rng.Formula, Chr(34))(1)
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strAddress
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This code adds hyperlink but My column B is already having hyperlink what I want to do is open those workbooks that are in the hyperlink.

Comment: @yashikavaish I have tested above code and then posted. There's altogether different syntax for adding hyperlink to cell.

Comment: I have values/hyperlink in my column B in the way mentioned below:

Comment: HYPERLINK("C:\Users\y\Documents\2018-01-05 12-15-50\KR41.xlsx")

Comment: But the given code is not able to open this KR41.xlsx workbook from the given path

Comment: @yashikavaish if you select cell, open immediate window and paste `?ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Count` then what value do you get.

Comment: It will give me 0

Comment: Ah, that is why it is failing as you have used a formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162576/discussion-between-shrivallabha-redij-and-yashika-vaish).